Arbitrage between one touch option and vanilla option
I recently came across this question, which is if you have a one touch option which the market has priced in X% of touching the barrier, and a vanilla call option on the same underlying and maturity that priced in Y% of touching the barrier such that X% is not equal to Y%. Is there any way to arbitrage between them?

It is probably not optimal talking about priced in probabilities in options as you would have to clarify if you mean real-world probabilities or risk neutral. You can approximate the price of a one touch option using two American options. This yields at least an arbitrage bound

@MrLCh I see, thanks for your reply. Is it possible to approximate the price using two European options instead? Or would it not be possible to hedge it without being able to exercise it earlier?
